# String comparison inside a LINQ query results in a nullable booelan?

Tags: linq

I have a very simple database. It s a name/value store for various configuration items and I'm trying to simply get them all out and into a list of items.

My LINQ query looks like this:

```
configurationList = (from c in database.Configurations select new ViewConfigurationSettingModel(c.name, c.value){ IsChanged = (c.name == id) } ).ToArray();
```

The class ViewConfigurationSettingModel looks like this:

```
public class ViewConfigurationSettingModel
{
    public ViewConfigurationSettingModel(string name, string value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
        this.IsChanged = false;
    }



    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public bool IsChanged { get; set; }
}
```

When I execute the LINQ query I get an exception because 'IsChanged' is not a nullable type and cannot contain null. I am stumped how `(c.name == id)` could result in a null. Both values are strings, but even a comparison with a null should result in a simple true of false.

What going on with LINQ that this all of a sudden results in a null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comparison with a null results in a simple true/false in C#, but not in SQL. I suspect that's the problem here. Assuming `id` is non-null, you could try something like:

```
IsChanged = c.name != null && (c.name == id)
```

If you can make the `name` column non-nullable in the database, that may help too...

Comment: That kinda makes sense. Your second suggestion doesn't work. The compiler doesn't accept it. The error states that you cannot use '??' with a boolean type. So it appears there is a big difference between what the compiler does and what happens at runtime when the expression is run.

Comment: @Jeroen-bartEngelen: Yes, I should have thought of that. Will edit to remove that suggestion. Interesting...